# Number of queries on array

Tags: rmq

I am looking at **Range minimum queries**.

**Wikipedia** says :

> There are Θ(n²) possible queries for a length-n array.

I do not understand that. Here is an **example** for an array of size 5. 
The following queries are possible :

> 1 query [0,4] 
>  2 queries [0,3] and [1,4] 
>  3 queries
>   [0,2],[1,3]and [2,4] 
>  4 queries [0,1],[1,2], [2,3] and [3,4]
>  5
>   queries [0],[1],[2],[3] and [4]

The total queries possible

> [0,4] + 
>  [0,3] + [1,4] + 
>  [0,2] + [1,3] + [2,4] + 
>  [0,1]
>   +[1,2] + [2,3] + [3,4] + 
>  [0] + [1] + [2] + [3] + [4]

--------------------------------- 
15 queries

But I am expecting `N^2 = 25` queries ( where N is array size = 5 )

What am I missing ? Could anyone explain ?

Comment: Θ(n²) is not equal to n² . Go through the concept again.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar you are correct. I see the difference. Θ(x) is tight uppper bound.                                                                                                          f(x) = Θ(g(x)) iff f(x) = O(g(x)) and f(x) = Ω(g(x))